# Exclude safari browser from Varnish caching

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Any suggestions how we can exclude devices that use Safari browser from using our Varnish caching? Excluding from varnish.vcl but what code to use?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but something like:

```cpp
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Safari") {
        return (pass);
    }
}
```